# Is there a limit on if's Or other things like it? (batch)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

so I am trying to make a start up menu for my computer. and all of the start ups work except the notepad one. now i have notepadp for notepad plus and just notepad for regular notepad. Am i missing something? I was wondering if there was a limit on how many if's you can have.

```
@echo off
color 02
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------
echo Welcome To Jex's Start Menu! Type What You Would like to start 
echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 --------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo. 
echo Here Is What I Can Start For Ya!
echo 1: Steam
echo 2: Google 
echo 3: Dicord
echo 4: Notepadp
echo 5: Notepad
set /p input=
if %input%==steam goto steam 
if %input%==Steam goto steam
if %input%==google goto google 
if %input%==Google goto google 
if %input%==discord goto discord
if %input%==Dicord goto discord
if %input%==notepadp goto np+
if %input%==Notepadp goto np+
if %input%==notepad goto np
if %input%==Notepad goto np
:steam
Start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe"
exit
:google
start www.google.com
exit
:discord
start /min "" "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Discord\app-0.0.297\Discord.exe"
exit 
:np+
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
exit
:np
start "" "%windir%\system32\notepad.exe"
exit
```

Comment: Try changing `np+` to `npp`. It's likely ignoring the plus and treating both labels the same (so only using the first).

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Im very new to batch so im trying to get basics down :)

Comment: Great! I'll put it as a proper answer, since it might help others in future.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use special characters in labels, like `+` or spaces, just enclose the label between quotes:

```
@echo off

goto "np+"

:np
echo Not here
goto :EOF

:"np+"
echo OK!
```

Comment: It should be mentioned here that the quotation marks become part of the label name here...

Answer (score 0):

As @Matthew says, the label `np+` causes an error. You will have to change it to something else. I also found a few problems in the batch file

*Spoiler:*

> **Line 4 and 7:** random `----` lines?
>  **Line 16:** `set /p` should be quoted
>  **Line 17 - 26:** use `if /i` to make it case-insensitive
> **Line 40:** use `notepad` command to start notepad

And again, the last and the important problem:

The `np+` error. You should avoid using these characters as a label name. If I were you, I will type `npp`(as @Matthew suggested) or `notepadPlusPlus`

Comment: The ---- lines are just for it to look nice and thanks for the tips! Im still learning alot of the commands.

Comment: You can use `REM` to act as an comment

Comment: Oh, BTW, some people uses `::` as label, but they're a bit more dangerous then `REM` when you get to a higher level of Widows Scripting

Comment: Ahhh ok :) im glad i found this website, its already helped alot. And thanks again

Comment: no problem :) you can also visit MSDN or ss64.com to find out more about Windows scripting

Comment: If i use that command it brings up a command shell that wont exit by its self

Comment: Yup. Command prompt and batch files have their own parser, so they work differently

Comment: Then why use it? it looks a bit ugly with the cmd open

Comment: Sorry. I am a bit confused about what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

Windows is ignoring the `+` in the label `np+`. So you effectively have two identical labels.

Change `np+` to `npp`.

[Some Microsoft documentation on `goto`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/goto.mspx?mfr=true) says:

> You can use spaces in the label parameter, but you cannot include other separators (for example, semicolons or equal signs). The goto command uses only the first eight characters of a label.

So presumably the plus sign comes under *other separators*.

Comment: ok so thats why it was not working. and yea ill check out those websites.